# Why is justify-content: flex-start; not working?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design

I was making a navbar using flexbox. By default, shouldn't the justify-content property be set  to flex-start; ? But the content inside my container is not begining from the start.
Here's the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tLlx.png) and code:

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: #ffeead;
  margin: 10px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.container {
  border: 5px solid #dff124;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.container li {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #ffeead;
  background-color: #96ceb4;
}

.search {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="container">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Profile</li>
    <li class="search">
      <input type="text" class="search-input" placeholder="Search">
    </li>
    <li>Logout</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: It's working fine. But you have set the input container to be as wide as possible.

Comment: You need to remove the default padding from the `ul` element. Add `padding: 0;` to the `ul` element.

Comment: I tried removing the styling for the input field. The issue still persists!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That white-space is caused by the default padding of the `<ul>`. You can remove it by adding: `ul { padding-left: 0; }`

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: #ffeead;
  margin: 10px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.container {
  border: 5px solid #dff124;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.container li {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #ffeead;
  background-color: #96ceb4;
}

.search {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="container">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Profile</li>
    <li class="search">
      <input type="text" class="search-input" placeholder="Search">
    </li>
    <li>Logout</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```